# Convert JSON with array of objects of unpredictable key-value-pairs to CSV

Tags: json, jq, openstreetmap

I've got this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "tag": [
      {
        "k": "name",
        "v": "Luxor"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "tag": [
      {
        "k": "name",
        "v": "Farflame"
      },
      {
        "k": "magic",
        "v": "30"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to create a CSV that has "id", "name" and "magic". If an element doesn't exist, an empty string should be set:

```
"id","name","magic"
"1","Luxor",""
"2","Farflame","30"
```

I'm nearly there, but I can't get the empty string if "magic" isn't present:

```
me@MBA test % jq -r '.[] | [.id, (.tag[] | select(.k=="name") | .v), (.tag[] | select(.k=="magic") | .v)] | @csv' simple.json
"1","Luxor"
"2","Farflame","30"
```

As you can see, the row with id "1" has only two cells, because there isn't a "magic" element inside of "tag". I tried all kinds of `if` statements, but wasn't able to find one that does what I want.

*Motivation*

The toy example above resembles the OSM XML code from OpenStreetMap exports. To import some OpenStreetMap data into a database, converting to a tabular structure is a crucial step. OSM stores all tags for a node (or way or relation) in an array of objects with keys "@k" and "@v"; you cannot predict which keys are present and in what order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` doesn't scale well. Instead, I would write a function similar to `from_entries` for converting `tag` arrays to objects, and use it like this:

```
def f: map({(.k): .v}) | add;
.[] | [.id] + (.tag | f | [.name, .magic]) | @csv
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bWXm6ZhHbA)</sup>